# attach() method doesnt attach foreign key value

Tags: php, laravel

i'm doing a project in laravel,but while trying to seed my database,i get this error
[seeding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VPTV.png)
[seeding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV1Is.png)

here is my company seeder
[company seeder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VPTV.png)

the productionline seeder
[production line seeder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQxvo.png)
the company model

will really appreciate if someone gets me out of this snug

Comment: Please add your code directly in your question, don't use images

Comment: The error is that the field pro_line_id cannot be null on the database, Eloquent might not be setting the correct ID if you not set the "belongsToMany" relation correctly. Can you show us how are you defining your "belongsToMany" relation?

Answer (score 0):

->attach() function accepts a model id as a parameter, not the object itself.

```
$dev->productionLine()->attach($dev_line->id);
```